# Kubernetes Mysql env not applied

Tags: mysql, kubernetes

In kubernetes statefulset, I set env 'MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD', 'MYSQL_USER', 'MYSQL_PASSWORD'.
but when i check pod, env not applied.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: mysql
  namespace: mysql
spec:
  serviceName: mysql
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mysql
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mysql
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: mysql
        image: mysql:8.2.0
        env:
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: root-password
        - name: MYSQL_USER
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: username
        - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mysql-secret
              key: password
        - name: MYSQL_ROOT_HOST
          value: '%'
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3306
          name: redis
        volumeMounts:
        - name: data
          mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: mysql-local
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
~
```

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: mysql-secret
  namespace: mysql
type: Opaque
data:
  root-password: YXNkZjE1MTU=
  password: YXNkZjE1MTU=
stringData:
  username: sueshin
```

i checked pod with exec -it.
in pod, echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD show right password.

i encoded secret with command 'echo -n 'password' | base64'. so i think this is not problem.

i also tried to add MYSQL_ROOT_HOST and value '%'.

below is describe pod

```
[root@master mysql]# k describe -n mysql pod mysql-0
Name:             mysql-0
Namespace:        mysql
Priority:         0
Service Account:  default
Node:             worker0/192.168.57.102
Start Time:       Fri, 08 Dec 2023 11:22:59 +0900
Labels:           app=mysql
                  apps.kubernetes.io/pod-index=0
                  controller-revision-hash=mysql-6cb4685fdc
                  statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name=mysql-0
Annotations:      cni.projectcalico.org/containerID: 3c86c6e7ef25296947f07f1864279d64a737ad879835c699c0b1e2e309054274
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIP: 192.168.204.97/32
                  cni.projectcalico.org/podIPs: 192.168.204.97/32
Status:           Running
IP:               192.168.204.97
IPs:
  IP:           192.168.204.97
Controlled By:  StatefulSet/mysql
Containers:
  mysql:
    Container ID:   containerd://54fc5d6d397bea60d502a75262ee9fbbadc26e9d9842544de819b2e1ef46d607
    Image:          mysql:8.2.0
    Image ID:       docker.io/library/mysql@sha256:1773f3c7aa9522f0014d0ad2bbdaf597ea3b1643c64c8ccc2123c64afd8b82b1
    Port:           3306/TCP
    Host Port:      0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Fri, 08 Dec 2023 11:22:59 +0900
    Ready:          True
    Restart Count:  0
    Environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD:  <set to the key 'root-password' in secret 'mysql-secret'>  Optional: false
      MYSQL_USER:           <set to the key 'username' in secret 'mysql-secret'>       Optional: false
      MYSQL_PASSWORD:       <set to the key 'password' in secret 'mysql-secret'>       Optional: false
      MYSQL_ROOT_HOST:      %
    Mounts:
      /var/lib/mysql from data (rw)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-qs5qh (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             True
  ContainersReady   True
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  data:
    Type:       PersistentVolumeClaim (a reference to a PersistentVolumeClaim in the same namespace)
    ClaimName:  data-mysql-0
    ReadOnly:   false
  kube-api-access-qs5qh:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type    Reason     Age    From               Message
  ----    ------     ----   ----               -------
  Normal  Scheduled  7m15s  default-scheduler  Successfully assigned mysql/mysql-0 to worker0
  Normal  Pulled     7m15s  kubelet            Container image "mysql:8.2.0" already present on machine
  Normal  Created    7m15s  kubelet            Created container mysql
  Normal  Started    7m15s  kubelet            Started container mysql
```

Comment: _"env not applied"_ and _"echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD show right password"_ seem to be conflicting statements

Comment: @Phil when i check 'echo $MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD', it shows right password. 
but 'mysql -uroot -p' and enter empty password successfuly get into mysql.
and check with 'select user from mysql.user', there is no user i added with MYSQL_USER....

Comment: I found why it was happend. it was pv problem....

Comment: Feel free to post an answer below. It might help others in the future

Comment: @Phil I posted an answer as you mentioned. Thanks for the reminder.